# coloring a line on canvas

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas, lines

I am trying to color the following line, but my canvas either colors all the lines or does not color at all. Any help would be appreciated

```
canvas.save();
canvas.scale(1, 0.75);
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.arc(100, 95, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
canvas.stroke();
canvas.strokeStyle= "red";
canvas.closePath();
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to color the line here. Did you make one?

Comment: canvas.fillStyle ="red";

Comment: Where? Please [include](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15797340/edit) it in the code.

Comment: Edit your post and put all the code in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using canvas, I assume you mean context.

canvas=getElementById("mycanvas");

context.getContext("2d");

A few points:
1. Start 1 or more draws with context.beginPath();
2. When you tell the context to context.stroke(), it will use the **last** strokeStyle you set (previous strokeStyles are ignored)
3. always to context.stroke() to physically apply your drawn lines,arcs,etc to the canvas.

```
// draw a red circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 95, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.strokeStyle="red";
context.stroke();

//then begin a new path and draw a blue circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(150, 95, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.strokeStyle="blue";
context.stroke();
```